# How to unmap Explorer key opening Nautilus window?

Tags: shortcut-keys, nautilus, launcher, gnome-shell, multimedia

Help! I am trying to map a custom command to the Explorer key on my keyboard, but my system seems to have the key mapped to open a Nautilus window somewhere other than Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts.

In Keyboard shortcuts > Launchers, Home folder has no mapping (says "Disabled"):

[image: Screenshot]

Then I go into Custom Shortcuts and create a mapping for the key I want, which is labeled "Explorer":

[image: Screenshot]

However, when I click on the key, I get a Nautilus window instead of the command I want. There must be somewhere else that this shortcut is mapped but I cannot locate it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Running: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS & GNOME Shell

Answer (score 1):

Unassign that media key as follows:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys home-static "['']"
```